# same ID to duplicate items in a python list

Tags: python, list

With the Python programming language, I wrote a program that gives the same ID to duplicate items in a list, but unfortunately I encountered a problem

for example, in the example below ,index 5 output should be [3, 'C', 'G'], but it gives[4, 'C', 'G'].
notice that the list is dynamic and it's just an example

```
my_list = [['A','F'], ['B','F'], ['B','F'], ['C','G'], ['A','F'], ['C','G'] , ['A','F'],['A','D']]

id_list = []
id_node_list = []
counter = 0
for item in my_list:
    if item in id_list:
        id = id_list.index(item) + 1
    else:
        counter += 1
        id = counter
    id_list.append(item)
    id_node_list.append([id,item[0],item[1]])
    
print(id_node_list)
```

output is:

```
[[1, 'A', 'F'], [2, 'B', 'F'], [2, 'B', 'F'], [3, 'C', 'G'], [1, 'A', 'F'], [4, 'C', 'G'], [1, 'A', 'F'], [4, 'A', 'D']]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2r2Y.jpg)

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:machine-learning] and [tag:deep-learning] when it's just list manipulation?

Comment: You do `id_list.append(item)` even if `item` was found in `id_list`. Make this line a part of the `else` block. Of course the different approach in mozways answer is even better. And you shouldn't use `id` as a name for your own variable, because you overwrite the built-in function [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use lists to store this kind of information, this makes searching inefficient.

You should use a dictionary:

```
mapper = {}
id_node_list = []
for item in my_list:
    id_node_list.append([mapper.setdefault(item[0], len(mapper)+1)]+item)

print(id_node_list)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [2, 'B'], [3, 'C'], [1, 'A'], [3, 'C'], [1, 'A']]
```

`mapper` in the end of the loop:

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

##### why your code failed

You `append` the `item` to `id_list` irrespective of its presence, thus inserting non wanted elements and incrementing the position of future items. You would have needed to put this in the `else`:

```
id_list = []
id_node_list = []
counter = 0
for item in my_list:
    if item in id_list:
        id = id_list.index(item) + 1
    else:
        counter += 1
        id = counter
        id_list.append(item)
    id_node_list.append([id, item[0]])
```

Comment: if my list has two index in each list like this:
my_list = [['A','F'], ['B','F'], ['B','G'], ['C','G'], ['A','F'], ['C','G'] , ['A','F']]
and i want to give same id to list that both index are the same
how can I handle your code??

Comment: This is a different question (which probably should been asked separately). The answer depends on the expected logic. Would you want to track the unique values or the pairs? In short one needs a full example with input/output to really know what you want.